# What's wrong with this php zip/image uploader?

Tags: php, image, upload, zip

I've been making an image uploader and I'm having a couple of issues.

Code is so simple: it gets a file (zip file) froom a form and a couple of info text, then generates an url if it isn't exists previously and then extracts the file there.

First one is, that the form variables (`$_post["serie"]` and `$_POST["capitulo"]` seems to expire if the file is large and take some time to upload.

Second one is that it tends to fail when uploading not jpg stuff >< and don't know why.

Thanks for your efforts in advance.

```
<?php 
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');

function preextract($p_event, &$p_header) {
    $info = pathinfo($p_header['filename']);
    if ($info['extension'] == 'gif' || $info['extension'] == 'jpg' || $info['extension'] == 'png' || $info['extension'] == 'jpeg') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
}

$archive = new PclZip($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$extractpath = "../series/" . $_POST["serie"] . "/" . $_POST["capitulo"];

echo $extractpath;

if (file_exists($extractpath)) {

} else {
   mkdir($extractpath, 0755);
}

if (($archive->extract(PCLZIP_OPT_PATH, $extractpath, PCLZIP_CB_PRE_EXTRACT, 'preextract') == 0)) {
    echo "\n error in extraction";
} else {
    echo "\n done";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things...

1. You need to increase the max filesize to submit larger files:

   ```
   ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize', '100M' );
   ini_set( 'post_max_size', '100M' );
   ```
2. Change your `file_exists` check:

   ```
   if ( !file_exists( $extractpath ) )
       mkdir( $extractpath, 0755 );
   ```
3. Change your extension check:

   ```
   return in_array( $info['extension'], array( 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' ) ) ? 1 : 0;
   ```

I'm not sure why it only works on one extension, maybe `PclZip` has a setting prohibiting certain files, so look for that.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you so much for your answer.

With "tens to fail" I mean that if I upload a zip folder containing jpg, everything is ok. But if I do the same with .png files, it didn't work.

Comment: Already seen, thanks again. Definitely, the problem must be the library, seems not to deal with png and gifs.

By the way, I don't know if it's possible to make a "progress bar" with php. Should I try to look for javascript/jquery uploaders or they won't let me to decompress and all that stuff?

Comment: There are JavaScript/jQuery plugins that would show upload progress, but you can't show decompression progress without modifying source code, flushing content, etc. It gets complicated.

Comment: Didn't want to show decompression progress, just be able to decompress after uploading. I should be able to do this - I think. I'll take a look outside, thanks for your help again.